# adjusting linked indexes for reorganized arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, dynamic-arrays

I have a table that can be dynamically styled with various colors and a palette of colors that serves as a reference to those colors. When the user has finished coloring, I want to compile the file to JSON. I can fetch the necessary values likewise:

```
// note _colors is a global variable declared elsewhere

var $rowSelect = $("#rowSelect");
var $colSelect = $("#colSelect");
var $colorBoard = $("#colorBoard");
var $upload = $("#upload");

$upload.on("click", function() {
    var numRows = Number($rowSelect.val());
    var numCols = Number($colSelect.val());

    var pixels = [];
    var colors = [];
    var comp_colors = [];

    var $rows = $colorBoard.children();
    for(var i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
        var $cols = $rows.eq(i).children();
        for(var ii = 0; ii < numCols; ii++) {
            $cell = $cols.eq(ii);
            pixels.push(Number($cell.attr("data-colorid")));
        }
    }

    var usedColors = pixels.filter((v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) === i);

    for(var i = 0; i < _colors.length; i++) {
        colors.push(_colors[i] ? _colors[i].color.getColor() : null);
        if(_colors[i] && usedColors.includes(i) && !comp_colors.includes(colors[i])) comp_colors.push(_colors[i].color.getColor());
    }
}
```

Since colors can be deleted, duplicated, or unused in my UI, I cleaned up my raw color array `colors` into the `comp_colors` array. For example, an array of unprocessed colors may look like: `[null, "#EF1A1A", null, "#40E255", "#0B1DE3", "#FFFFFF", "#FFFFFF"]`. If `"#0B1DE3"` was not actually present in our pixel array, the cleaned up version would look like: `["#EF1A1A", "#40E255", "#FFFFFF"]`.

The problem is that cleaning up the color array has offset the indexes that the values of the `pixels` array were using to reference the colors. For example, using the color situation above, a fetched array of `pixels` may look like this: `[1,3,3,1,5,6,5,1,3,6]`, but the revised version for the cleaned up color set would be: `[0,1,1,0,2,2,2,0,1,0]`.

What is the most efficient way to correct these values to the appropriate indexes?

Answer (score 0):

I found a concise method, but I don't feel like it is very efficient. I have to iterate through every pixel to achieve this, which can be costly at with large creations. The new list of `pixels` will be loaded into `comp_pixels`:

```
for(var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) comp_pixels.push(comp_colors.indexOf(colors[pixels[i]]));
```